# Как сохранить значения, введенные в форму, при переходе на другую страницу?

Tags: php, php7

У меня есть форма авторизации на сайте. При клике на кнопку "Войти" вас перебрасывает на другую страницу. Как сделать так, что бы при переходе на другую страницу, сохранялись данные, введённые в форме на предыдущей странице?

Comment: после авторизации сохраните данные в сессию

Comment: @teran, увы, сессии я еще не изучил...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самый простой способ, это form, на первой странице

```
<form action="handler.php">
   <input type="text">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

На второй принимай через $_POST

Comment: то есть мне нужно обрабатывать форму во втором файле?

Comment: Аууу. Ответьте пожалуйста.

Comment: разъясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: я вас не понял. Просил разъяснить ответ. Реакции ноль...

Comment: Покажите код инпута и кнопки на первой странице, чтоб понять как вы переходите на другую страницу

Comment: Перекинуть данные пол дела. Другое что после обновления страницы они сбросятся. А тут как раз вам надо учить сессии. Там легко, делов на 10 минут.

Comment: По логике если это окно авторизации, то нужно не перекидывать, а записывать в сессию. А потом проверять на всех страницах, если сессия есть, то пользователь зареган, и от туда брать что за пользователь. Если сессия пустая, то выпадает окно регистрации

Comment: спасибо, понял. Очень благодарен))